# Retrieving aspect/sun exposition of geographic locations using code (e.g. python, commandline, ...)

Tags: geopandas, geography, aspect, topography

I am looking for a tool/way to infer the topographic aspect of a location (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_(geography)) or its sun exposition in hours of sun/year in an automated way.

To further explain my problem:
I have a list of locations (with coordinates) in the alps. I want to know towards which compass direction its slope is facing. I want to retrieve a list of these aspects (in degrees) or (if it is easier) sun exposition times (e.g. in hours per year/month).

Does anyone know automated ways to do so?

I was looking online but did not find a good way so far.